# Sympy integrate() does not produce output in the natural form of the common fraction

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

This code is taken from the Sympy tutorial:

```
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
x = Symbol('x')
r = integrate(x**2 + x + 1, x)

print(r)
```

The output is: `x**3/3 + x**2/2 + x`

It's correct, but in [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html) the output was:

```
 3    2
x    x
-- + -- + x
3    2
```

How can I reach this form of output?

*If necessary: **IDE** is pyCharm, **python ver.** is 3.3*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pretty printer `pprint` instead of normal `print`. Refer the Sympy Tutorial section [Printing](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/tutorial.html#printing)

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> r = integrate(x**2 + x + 1, x)
>>> print(r)
x**3/3 + x**2/2 + x
>>> pprint(r)
 3    2    
x    x     
-- + -- + x
3    2
```

**Note** For non string objects, [print statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) (Python 2.X) or the [print function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print)  (Python 3.X) converts the object to string using the [rules for string conversion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just fine. What is the reason you're writing ">>>" at the beginning of the each line of your code?

Comment: That's what the code looks like in an interactive Python session (like if you type `python` at the command line).

Comment: The various options to `init_printing` that you've used here are generally not necessary. Unless you find that the default output is not optimal, the defaults are generally the best way to go.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're just copying what was used in the tutorial. Those options are just there because the Unicode tends to not look so good in a web-browser (and the other options are for the automatic doctesting of examples).